# I am needing to collect a table of information that is normally gathered through a search. Web Scraping Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

We have a website that we use to determine the warehouse availability of a part. It's a password protected site, but we have legitimate authorized access. Normally we request parts information one at a time for counter sales, and it pulls up the warehouses that stock it. I am wanting to go the other way and find the local warehouse and collect all the parts they stock. I am assuming there is a database that they upload this information to and when we search a part number it queries it. How can I collect all of that database so I can parse out the warehouse skus. Without doing something as massive as running a script that searches part number 000001 - 999999 and collects warehouse and stock from the generated page.

For some reason the warehouse has been unable to provide a listing. We have already asked, they are trying but I don't hold much faith.

I have scoured the source code using Chromes handy view source tables and events but nothing stuck out as being the route to the database. Where should I at least start?

Thanks,
Corey

Comment: If the site you are working with is well made: nowhere. It won't reveal the database-parameters to the client, the app-server will manage the database-connection.

Comment: It's likely well made. So is building something to do repeated queries... from #0001- #9999 is probably my only option?

Comment: Talk to the warehouse-people and let them give you a dump of the database.

Comment: From my own experience there is almost certainly a way to do what you want. Try poking around the network tab on chrome and try to determine how there system is working by examining the request parameters if you can see them. It really depends on how the system is constructed which I cannot determine from your question.